# How can I find the average of N colors?

Tags: javascript, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I'm looking for a way to find the average of an unspecified number of colors. I spent a lot of time looking for a way to do this. First I tried converting my colors to CMYK and averaging them, but that didn't provide the result I expected. Then I saw that in several different places, converting the colors to CIE L*a*b* space and then averaging is the preferred way of doing this. So I looked up how to convert RGB colors to LAB space and converted into Javascript the necessary algorithms to make this happen.

Now that I have my colors in LAB space, I thought it would be as simple as finding the average of my colors, so I wrote this function to do the trick:

```
color.mixRGB = function() {
    var cols = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        i = cols.length,
        lab = {l: 0, a: 0, b: 0};

    while(i--) {
        if (typeof cols[i].r === "undefined" && typeof cols[i].g === "undefined" && typeof cols[i] === "undefined") {
            console.log("Not enough parameters supplied for color " + i + ".");
            return;
        }

        if(cols[i].r === 0 && cols[i].g === 0 && cols[i].b === 0) {
            cols.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            cols[i] = color.RGBtoLAB(cols[i]);
            lab.l += cols[i].l;
            lab.a += cols[i].a;
            lab.b += cols[i].b;            
        }
    }

    lab.l /= cols.length;
    lab.a /= cols.length;
    lab.b /= cols.length;

    return color.LABtoRGB(lab);
};
```

If I enter RGB (255, 0, 0) and RGB(0, 0, 255) into the function, I get RGB(202, -59, 136). This color is nothing near what Color Hexa says is the average of those two RGBs, which is RGB (128, 0, 128), a.k.a purple.

I went back over all my code, and so far I've managed to determine that the problem does not lie with any of my conversion algorithms by double- and triple-checking them against [Color Hexa](http://colorhexa.com) and [EasyRGB](http://easyrgb.com). That means either a) the issue must lie with how I'm averaging the colors or b) I've been misinformed and I shouldn't attempt to mix colors in CIE L*a*b* space.

What exactly am I missing here? Using my current algorithm, why is averaging RGB (255, 0, 0) and RGB (0, 0, 255) not giving me the same results that Color Hexa (or even visual estimation) provides? ([here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeDPc/10/) of my problem)

Comment: Averaging in one colour space is not the same as averaging in a different colour space.  One wouldn't expect the same results.

Comment: I understand that; why is it relevant?

Comment: Because you seem to be surprised that you're obtaining different results ;)  (Although possibly I'm misreading things...)

Comment: Well, I was hoping to get somewhat similar results, if not exactly the same. Two colors have a definitive average, right? Color Hexa seems to provide a close approximation of what my visual estimation of averaging red and blue would be (purple), whereas my algorithm isn't.

Comment: Color Hexa seems to work on RGB taking mere average of pairs in each channel.

Comment: @DavidJashi Care to elaborate? I'd just like to achieve the same results that they are getting. I'm not worried about *how* I get them.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: "Colours have a definitive average" -not really ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Red + blue visually averages to purple, right? That's what I was getting at, even if it was poorly worded.

Comment: I thought I just did, actually. OK, I'll put it as an answer in more detailed way.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. If you are defining the rgb as the correct benchmark, then do the average in rgb. Your ultimate red component is the average of the red components of all the colours, and the same for green and blue. Obviously you will need to round to the nearest whole number, but that can't be too bad.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: That intuition only corresponds to certain colour spaces.  Take [this image](http://tramped-rose.blogspot.com/2012/04/color-wheel-for-pastel-colored-denim.html) for example; is white the average of orange and blue?  Or is it green?  Or mauve?  In RGB it is likely none of these.

Comment: O.O Apparently not. I stand corrected. So that means that those people who were talking about getting a visual average of two colors by converting to LAB and averaging were incorrect?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: I'm not familiar with LAB (I'm definitely not a colour expert ;) ).  But perhaps it has properties that mean that the result of operations like averaging correspond closely to one's intuition.

Comment: Mm, okay. Well, thanks for your help.

Comment: Try HLS or HSB, you may like the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have your colors defined by R0, G0, B0 and R1, G1, B1. Then blended/average color will have following RGB values:

```
RA = (R0+R1)/2;
GA = (G0+G1)/2;
BA = (B0+B1)/2;
```

Thats it, basically.

Comment: I think I must be missing something. Can it really be that simple? I coded this algo up and I'm just doing a little testing.

Comment: Well, this is Color Hexa way. Which is not right, if you ask me. Try doing the same in HLS or HSB color space. LaB might be confusing for that.

Comment: Well, this seems to do the trick (it's certainly all I need). I guess I'm going to go accept your answer for now. Thanks for being the voice of common sense while I was off gallivanting about with overly complicated color spaces. :-)

Comment: You need to round to a whole number, see my solution.

Answer (score 2):

A null return means there has been an error.

```
color.mixRGB = function() {
   var cols = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
       i = cols.length,
       rTotal = 0, gTotal = 0, rTotal = 0, colTotal = 0;

   while(i--) {
       // NOTE: you had && in your code, I think they should be ||
       if (typeof cols[i].r === "undefined" || typeof cols[i].g === "undefined" || typeof cols[i] === "undefined") {
            console.log("Not enough parameters supplied for color " + i + ".");
            return null;
        }
        colTotal++;
        rTotal += cols[i].r;
        gTotal += cols[i].g;
        bTotal += cols[i].b;
    }
    if(colTotal === 0) return null;

    // I am not sure what you are trying to return, just build it up with your rgb values
    return (new color(Math.round(rTotal / colTotal), Math.round(gTotal / colTotal), Math.round(bTotal / colTotal)));
};
```